# F# How to avoid twice cast

Tags: casting, f#, pattern-matching, seq

### Case 1

1. Take elements while is Some value from sequense
2. Print values of some

```ml
let a = seq { yield Some 1; yield Some 2; yield Some 3; yield None }

a
|> Seq.takeWhile Option.isSome // cast 1
|> Seq.map Option.get          // cast 2
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

### Case 2

1. Filter sequense of Some vaue
2. Print values of Some

```ml
a
|> Seq.filter Option.isSome    // cast 1
|> Seq.map Option.get          // cast 2
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

### Case 3

1. Group by elements by type
2. Print values of each group

```ml
type AB =
    | A of a : int
    | B of b : string

let a = seq{
    yield A 1
    yield A 2
    yield B "ds"
    yield B "fsdf"
}

let (|As|Bs|) = function
    | A _ -> As
    | B _ -> Bs

let matcher = function
    | A a-> printfn "%A" a
    | B b -> printfn "%A" b

a
|> Seq.groupBy (|As|Bs|)       // cast 1
|> Seq.map snd
|> Seq.iter (Seq.iter matcher) // cast 2
```

### Why do I need to avoid double casting?

- To keep the code cleaner
- To avoid throwing exceptions

Comment: What's the problem that you're trying to solve? Your three examples do quite different things and produce different results.

Comment: Oh no, these are not options to solve the problem, but cases reproducing the general problem.  I want to avoid re-matching with the same pattern.

Comment: In Haskell, I could try in one template to match both the list and the structure of the list items. And the list in Haskell works lazily as a sequence in f#.

Comment: It's not a general problem. The "cases" do completely different things. And you're therefore effectively asking three different questions in one post, which is usually frowned upon. See [ask]. Also, while case 2 is a common enough scenario, case 1 seems highly specialized and case 3 concerns a user-defined type. You can of course write functions similar to `Seq.choose` for these as well, but you'll have to do so yourself. It doesn't make sense to provide built-in functions that barely anyone will ever use. That's just clutter.

Comment: @glennsl I may be wrong but the problem seems to be common. First, perform an operation on a sequence (filtering, cropping, grouping) depending on the subtype of the element. Next you need to get the values of elements and perform an operation on them depending on the subtype. In these cases, the subtype from type is casting twice.

Comment: Perhaps I do not know what is based in F #. Perhaps I did not clearly describe the essence of the problem. I'm sorry!

Comment: What you're describing is a two-step process. You can't reduce that to one operation in general, but will have to rewrite each specific "operation" to combine the two steps into one.

Comment: Also, since the third case uses a user-defined type there is no single "value" to extract. Each variant may have several values, or none at all. There might also be any number of variants. So which would you pick, in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you're working with lists,** you can do the same thing you do in Haskell (which, judging by your comments, you know already). F# also has pattern matching, and it works much the same way, except the language is not lazy, so you'd have to account for that. For example:

```
let rec case2 xs = 
    match xs with
    | (Some x)::rest -> printfn "%A" x; case2 rest
    | None::rest -> case2 rest
    | [] -> ()
```

(note: if you're doing explicit recursion, it's a good idea to keep it to the "tail" variety; in Haskell this doesn't matter much due to laziness, but in .NET you can easily blow the stack if you're not careful)

---

**If you're working with sequences,** the situation is a bit more complicated. For some things you can use computation expressions (they are somewhat related to the `do` notation in Haskell):

```
let case2 xs = seq {
    for x in xs do
        match x with | Some a -> yield a | None -> ()
}
```

Or in some cases, standard library functions:

```
let case2 xs = Seq.choose id xs
```

(note: the above example can't be eta-reduced due to value restriction)

But your first example ("early stop") can't be expressed declaratively like that. You still have to use `takeWhile`, but at least you can then use `choose` instead of `map` to avoid using partial functions:

```
let case1 xs = xs |> Seq.takeWhile Option.isSome |> Seq.choose id
```

If you really-really want to have a single pattern match instead of two, it is possible to go one level deeper and use the `IEnumerable` interface directly:

```
let case1 (xs: seq<_>) = seq {
  use e = xs.GetEnumerator()
  let mutable stop = false

  while not stop && e.MoveNext() do
    match e.Current with
    | Some x -> yield x
    | None -> stop <- true
}
```

Note that this uses mutable variables, and while it looks ugly at first glance, it's worth remembering that iterating over .NET sequences (aka `IEnumerable<'t>`) is an inherently mutation-based process. Look above: the `e.MoveNext()` call changes the state of enumerator `e`. You have to deal with this fact if you want to go down to this level.

And of course, I could have eliminated the `stop` variable by replacing it with recursion:

```
let case1 (xs: seq<_>) = seq {
  use e = xs.GetEnumerator()

  let rec loop() = seq {
    if e.MoveNext() then
      match e.Current with
      | Some x -> yield x; yield! loop()
      | None -> ()
  }

  yield! loop()
}
```

But this is rather silly: if I'm willing to deal with the mutable enumerator, I might as well just go all in.

---

**As for your third example** - I don't understand what you're even trying to do there. Or, rather, I do understand what it does, but I don't see what it would mean to get rid of the second match. Perhaps you could illustrate how you'd do the same thing in Haskell?

Answer (score 5):

For "Case 2" you can use `Seq.choose` with the identity function, `id`:

```
a
|> Seq.choose id
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.choose%5b%27t%2c%27u%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d) for `Seq.choose` says

> Applies the given function to each element of the list and returns the list comprised of the results for each element where the function returns Some with some value.

Passing it the identity function will therefore return the content of every `Option` value that is `Some`.